HttpClient timeout - data response vs request completion
I have an application that has to download a large payload (a few hundred MB), and in some circumstances on a device with a slow connection.
So I have this:
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(activeResource.Content);
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);
    binary = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(activeResource.Content);
}

I've set the Timeout to be 6 hours to be safe - in realistic terms we have seem instances where it has taken up to an hour to download.
My question is: Does this Timeout specify the timeout for the entire transaction, or is it the timeout while waiting for a response?
In other words, what I want is, to allow for up to 6 hours (or thereabouts) for the entire download to complete, but if, say there is no data coming through, due to, say a dropped connection, I don't want the user to have to wait 6 hours to find out.
And if it's the former, how do I set a short timeout for waiting for a response from the server, but allow a long time for the download to complete?

If your connection drops (e.g. deactivate network controller), you will get an HttpRequestException

@Aaron - I actually get an OperationCancelledException, but only after the HttpClient.Timeout has elapsed.

What ended up doing the trick was a variation of Jeevan Abi's answer
I ditched the TimeOut property altogether and put the read into a cancellable task.
{
    var downloadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);
    var inactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(downloadTimeout);
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(resource.ResourceUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationTokenSource.Token))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            
            using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
                {
                    var buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int bytesRead;
                    long totalBytesRead = 0;

                    while ((bytesRead = await ReadDataAsync(contentStream, buffer, 0, buffer.Length, inactivityTimeout, cancellationTokenSource.Token)) > 0)
                    {
                        await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}


private async Task<int> ReadDataAsync(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    var readTask = Task.Run(() => stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count), cancelToken);

    if (await Task.WhenAny(readTask, Task.Delay(timeout)) == readTask)
    {
        return await readTask;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("Connection timed out during download.");
    }
}


Answers:

Does this Timeout specify the timeout for the entire transaction, or is it the timeout while waiting for a response?


The Timeout property in HttpClient defines the maximum time that the entire operation (from sending the request to receiving the response) can take before it is aborted.


And if it's the former, how do I set a short timeout for waiting for a response from the server, but allow a long time for the download to complete?

To handle this situation, you can use a combination of HttpClient.Timeout, CancellationToken and you can download the content as a stream, which gives you more control.
Updated Implementation:
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);

    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(activeResource.Content, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using (var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream("yourFileName", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            long totalBytesRead = 0;

            var inactivityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2); // Set inactivity timeout
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(inactivityTimeout);

            while ((bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationTokenSource.Token)) != 0)
            {
                await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                // Reset the inactivity timeout each time data is received
                cancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(inactivityTimeout);
            }
        }
    }
}

Explanation:

HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead : Rather than waiting for the entire content. This allows you to process the stream directly.

Reading the Stream :  you can detect inactivity and reset a short timeout (inactivityTimeout) each time data is received. If no data is received for a set period, the CancellationToken will trigger and cancel the operation.



This doesn't appear to work - if I disconnect from the network during the download it seems to get stuck in the 'ReadAsync' call and doesn't cancel after the timeout. It doesn't even timeout now after the longer timeout set to HttpClient! If, however, I leave the network connected, but don't reset the cancellation token it does cancel after the inactivityTimeout.

For allow a long time for the download to complete
You can try this -
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); // 30-second timeout for 
reading response
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
 {
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(activeResource.Content);
   client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(6); // 6-hour timeout for entire operation
   binary = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(activeResource.Content);
 }


HttpClientHandler doesn't seem to have a property called ReadTimeout ...
